# Any idea why "Service Providers" isn't an option in Google Analytics Reporting API?

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

In Google Analytics I've created a Dashboard which shows me ISPs.

According to https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets#cats=visitor

There is no "Service Provider" option... but strangely there is:

> ga:networkDomain
>
> The domain name of the ISPs used by visitors to your website. This is
>   derived from the domain name registered to the IP address.

Service Provider traditionally returns something like "university of maryland" where the Network Domain gives results like "umd.edu" it's effectively 1-1.  So, I don't see why they would intentionally exclude Service Providers from the API and not also network domain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ga:networkLocation
>
> The name of service providers used to reach your website

Dunno why they didn't just call serviceProviders instead... but oh well.

Here's a sample query which makes use of it:
https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v3/data/ga?ids=ga%YOUR_ID&dimensions=ga%3AnetworkLocation&metrics=ga%3Avisits&filters=ga%3AnetworkLocation!~(verizon%7Ccomcast%7Csprint)&sort=-ga%3Avisits&start-date=2012-08-08&end-date=2012-08-22&max-results=50